# Adding 1 to row value onsubmit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to know how to add 1 to a value in a nested div anytime the form is submitted.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="submit">
  <table width="30%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td width="58%"><div class="fav_count">1</div></td>
      <td width="42%"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="form2" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="submit">
  <table width="30%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td width="58%"><div class="fav_count">2</div></td>
      <td width="42%"><input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="form3" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="submit">
  <table width="30%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td width="58%"><div class="fav_count">3</div></td>
      <td width="42%"><input type="submit" name="button3" id="button3" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
<form id="form4" name="form1" method="post" action="" class="submit">
  <table width="30%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
    <tr>
      <td width="58%"><div class="fav_count">4</div></td>
      <td width="42%"><input type="submit" name="button4" id="button4" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

here's a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fgu42nxr/

Any help with jquery will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: When _form is submitted_, Page will get `redirected/reloaded` hence `DOM-manipulations` will not be persistent..

Comment: @RayonDabre right man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above, you can't do it when you submitting the form, because it leads to page reloading. However, you can cancel default form submit behaviour and reimplement it with ajax or something. If so, you can do it like this:

```
$("#form1").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // do some stuff here...
    $(this).find(".fav_count").each(function() {
        $(this).text(+($(this).text()) + 1)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding a class to your submit buttons and writing a click event of the same to update the value of fav_count.

Change your submit button to follow.

```
<input type="submit" class="cSubmitBtn" name="button4" id="button4" value="Submit" />
```

Now write a click event for above button to get the current value of fav and update it.

In the following code we're getting current fav value using parent() function of the jQuery then increase the current value by one.

And in last we're setting the value as text to the same span element using .text(value) function of jQuery.

```
$('.cSubmitBtn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    var favDiv=$(this).parents('tr').find('.fav_count');
    var currentValue=parseInt(favDiv.text());
    currentValue++;
    favDiv.text(currentValue);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fgu42nxr/3/

> Please note above code will prevent your submit button to submit the form on click. If you still want to submit the form you can do in the same jQuery code.

Comment: the answer works correctly but i just place the div a table above the form and it fails to work

Answer (score 1):

Here you have a solution => [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/roiEnwqsofqJUv1p3wND?p=preview)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("form").submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $div = $(this).find(".fav_count");
  var count = parseInt($div.html());
  count++;
  $div.html(count.toString());
 });  
});
```